# Spring read multipart attachment as input stream

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I'm developing a spring web service.Is there a way to read Multipart attachments in a soap message as a input stream with spring?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Spring framework do you use?

if you are using 4.0 please refer this document.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html

Answer (score 0):

refer this url it will may be help you
http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using multipart/form-data, you can use httpservletRequest inputstream to upload a file directly using curl command.

@RestController
public class MyController {

```
@RequestMapping(path="/load", method=RequestMethod.POST )
public ResponseEntity<?> streamData(HttpServletRequest request) {

  InputStream dataStream = request.getInputStream();
```

...
}

From Git bash, you can invoke using

$ curl -T initialFeed.txt -X POST http://localhost:8080/load

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-T